# In R: preprocessing for user segmentation

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using R and have a dataframe with columns:

```
user_id brand_id gender ...
```

I want to create a new dataframe with each user_id appearing only once and with colums:

```
#brand1-#occurences #brand2-#occurrences ... male female ...
```

So I then could use the normal clustering methods.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to [reshape data from long to wide in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)?

Comment: Welcome! It is difficult to start generating ideas just from what you have provided.
Please provide us with a small, reproducible code snippet that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions. You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for detailed instructions.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you want to reshape you data frame. Make two columns (female, male) from the one column (gender). The "array_reshape"-function from the reticulate package might help you.